# Use S3 bucket as a mounted drive or EBS volume on EC2?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ebs

I have an application that writes the logs on the server, it is a windows server. By increasing the logs the disk drive used space, increases and we have to scale up the volume from time to time. Scaling up the Disk Drive (EBS volume) doesn't seem very efficient way.

I'm wondering if we mount a S3 bucket as a mounted drive on EC2 for saving the logs there, is the best way or if there is any better way for that?

Comment: Why not rotate the logs off to S3 periodically?

Comment: @ceejayoz The application doesn't support it unfortunately.

Comment: The application doesn't have to. Log rotation is, in fact, *usually* handled by another dedicated process.

Comment: What will you be doing with the logs? Analytics, forward to a log search engine. Archival, rotate to cheap (object) storage.

Comment: There are applications around that let you mount an S3 bucket as a file system. I don't know how reliable they are.

Comment: @ceejayoz In the application setup we specify the path of saving the logs and this location must be a local path and exist on each machine in the site, today it is C:\arcgisservice\logs\ we can not put there a S3 bucket path. We use the logs for troubleshooting.

Comment: @Matrix Again, that's not a problem. Store logs locally. Have them rotated out of that folder onto S3. Your application doesn't have to support S3 for any of this.

Comment: @ceejayoz that means write a script to transfer the logs from local drive to s3 bucket for example once a day with cronjob? If so, yeah that is for sure possible.

Answer (score 0):

Have the application write logs to CloudWatch and/or an S3 Bucket periodically and then wipe older logs on your instance so that you don't have to increase EBS size. S3 cant be attached as a volume like you say, but it can be used as a delivery point for your logs externally.

Comment: No unfortunately the application (Arcgis Service) doesn't support either CloudWatch log or S3 bucket. So it can't write logs directly to them. So the only way can be with a script that collect the logs from the drive and upload it to a s3 bucket every day?